# Pentaho Dashboard issue-"Dashboards.addParameter is not a function in BA platform"

Tags: dashboard

I am using the Pentaho BI Server-CE. When I try to preview the dashboard,it shows error processing component.when I try to inspect using fire-bug,I got this error in console "Dashboards.addParameter is not a function in BA platform"